# Vagrant Apache2 http/https port forwarding

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lamp, vagrant, portforwarding

I am using Vagrant to manage Ubuntu instance for testing a web application. I am having trouble setting up its login page over https. As the application is using Apache2+php5+mysql. I have setup port forwarding sth like this to access the application from Host machine .

`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080`

When I try to access guest using `http://localhost:8080`, it redirect to `https://localhost:8080`
  Which seams reasonable ,but the 8080 port is forwarded to http:80 guest port not to https:43.
  so url `https://localhost:8080` is half true half a lie . I don't know how to forward https port to guest https port but  I wonder what will happen of `https://localhost:8080` redirect since that is not valid url is should be ( as I think ) sth like `https://localhost:4343`, if https:4343 is forwarded to guest:43. But application is not aware of the ports , it just changes `http` with `https`

(forgive me for the gibberish )

How I setup Vagrant network setting to access guest Apache http:80 and https:43 ports. Can I assigned a static IP to guest instance and use that pleasantly .

regards

using:

Vagrant version 1.1.5

Ubuntu precise64.box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, the default Networking mode - NAT is not a good choice because you have multiple ports (at least 80 and 443) to be forwarded.

I recommend using bridged mode so that the guest appears to be a physical host in your LAN and you will be able to access HTTP/HTTPS using its LAN IP. You don't need to do port forwarding (actually you cannot do port forwarding in VirtualBox for bridged mode).

To use bridge mode (Public Network), in your `Vagrantfile` add `config.vm.network :public_network` into the `Vagrant.configure` block and do a `vagrant reload`, it should work flawlessly. Use `ifconfig -a` to check, a 2nd interface will be added for bridged.

Reference: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html

Comment: I was afraid someone will ask me for that . Actually DHCP is not under my control , I have to ask LAN admin to enable my instance MAC address to work with DHCP. I was in search to avoid that hassle. Could it be possible with private staitic ip , only visible to my Host OS ?

Comment: Yes, of course you can use Private Network (believed to be Host-only in VirtualBox). VirtualBox provides a virtual networking engine (router) in between the host and guest, you can assign static IPs to the VMs. It is documented: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html